# Translating English into First-order Logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm trying to write this sentence in first-order logic but I do not know where to start:

*If there is at least one rational point on a circle, then there are infinitely many rational points on the circle.*

I tried these:
$$ p(x): x \in circle$$
$$(\exists x \in \mathbb{Q})(p(x) \to ???)$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Well, I think its not first order.

Comment: Were you given any predicates?  If not, you can always use $P$ ... that's still part of FOL. ... :P

Answer (score 1):

Infinity is not [definable](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/model-theory/#:%7E:text=Thus%20the%20formula,definable%20with%20parameters.) in first-order predicate logic (the routine method to show this is to use the [compactness theorem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#:%7E:text=Corollary%2022.%20Compactness,is%20satisfiable.)). However, that does not entail that statements involving the notion infinity cannot be be *expressible* in its language (some authors use the term 'expressible' for 'definable', but it is better to reserve the word 'expressible' for such usages as the present one).

Let us take a monadic predicate $P$ that associates each $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ with a point on a circle whose set of points has the cardinality of real numbers and define other non-logical predicates $<,\in$ as usual. Thus, we have first-order logic with identity and the structure $\mathcal{Q}$

$$\langle \mathbb{Q}, \in, <, P\rangle$$

Then, we can write the following first-order sentence that is a translation of the statement in the question:

$$\exists xPx\rightarrow \forall x\exists y(x<y\wedge\forall z(z<y\rightarrow\neg(Pz=Py)))$$